# Requesting file via PHP fails, but succeeds in Python

Tags: php, python, xml

The URL in question : http://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=149996624

When accessed in a browser, it will correctly download a file (which is an XML document). I wanted to get the file in php, and simply display its contents on a page.

```
$contents = file_get_contents("http://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=149996624");
```

The above is what I've tried using (as far as I know, the page does not expect any headers). I get a 500 HTTP error. However, in Python, the following code works and I receive the file.

```
r = requests.get("http://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=147781188")
```

I'm confused as to what the distinction is between how these two requests are sent. I am almost 100% it is not a header problem. I've also tried the cURL library in PHP to no avail. Nothing I've tried in PHP seems to succeed with the URL (with any valid id parameter); but Python is able to bring success nonchalantly.

Any insight as to why this issue may be happening would be great.

**EDIT** : I have already tried copying Python's headers into my PHP request.

**EDIT2** : It also appears that there are two requests happening upon navigating to the link.

Answer (score 0):

Is this on a linux/mac host by chance? If so you could use ngrep to see the differences on the request themselves on the wire. Something like the following should work

`ngrep -t '^(GET) ' 'src host 127.0.0.1 and tcp and dst port 80'`

**EDIT - The problem is that your server is responding with a 302 and the PHP library is not following it automatically. Cheers!**

Comment: The first status code is 302, but it is being redirected (as file_get_contents follows redirects) which ends up on the 500 page. So the PHP library is following it fine.